# Can't install typings in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript-typings

I am getting an error when installing my typings.

Command Prompt(inside my project) > type `typings install`. But the result is:

`This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.`

[image]

Has anyone experience this issue? and how to solved this?

Thanks!

Comment: have you installed `typings` globally using `npm install typings -g` ? If so, try running the command prompt with elevated rights. Or tell your PC that you own him

Comment: yes, I did it using cmd(run as admin) then install the typings `npm install typings --global`

Comment: try installing it without admin rights :) and running without

Comment: unfortunately, I still get the same issue, I installed it as a normal user, then run the `typings install`. Is there a way to uninstall it again? (sorry newbie here..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue after uninstalling CryptoPrevent.

Since npm directory contains .cmd(for typescripts), CryptoPrevent detect it as a malware/ransomware.

If you have other third-party software for ransomware, you can add npms to whitelist to avoid issues.